# Operation defining a fundamental group is well defined and associative

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Consider the aplication $\ast: \Pi_{1}(X,x_{0}) \times \Pi_{1}(X,x_{0}) \rightarrow \Pi_{1}(X,x_{0})$, defined by $\ast: ([\alpha] , [\beta]): \rightarrow [\alpha] \ast [\beta]$, from where

$$\Pi_{1}(X,x_{0})=\Omega(X, x_{0})/ \simeq$$

$\Omega(X, x_{0})$ denotes the space of loops over a fixed point $x_{0}$, and $\alpha \simeq \beta$ if

$$(\exists F:[0, 1] \times I) \rightarrow X)(F(s, 0)=\alpha(s), F(s, 1)=\beta(s) \quad \text{and} \quad F(0, t)=F(1, t)=x_{0})$$
My idea is to see that this application is well defined and associative.

To see that it is well defined, I thought it might be analogous to the operation induced on the homotopy classes of paths, i.e. to consider

$$\alpha \ast \beta= \left\{ \begin{array}{ll} \alpha(2x) & \text{if } x \in [0,\frac{1}{2}]\\ \beta(2x-1) & \text{if } x \in [\frac{1}{2},1]\\  \end{array} \right.$$

If I consider to evaluate at $t=\frac{1}{2}$ it could work, but I don't see it at all, since we could also see that if $\alpha \simeq \alpha'$ and $\beta \simeq \beta'$ then

$$\alpha \ast \beta \simeq \alpha' \ast \beta'$$

But how could this be done?

On the other hand, to prove associativity the idea could be based on seeing that $\alpha \ast (\beta \ast \delta)$ is a reparametrization of $(\alpha \ast \beta) \ast \delta$.

We know that if $\alpha \ast (\beta \ast \delta)$ reparametrizes to $(\alpha \ast \beta) \ast \delta$ then $\alpha \ast (\beta \ast \delta) \simeq (\alpha \ast \beta) \ast \delta$ and
$$[\alpha \ast (\beta \ast \delta) ]=[(\alpha \ast \beta) \ast \delta]$$

we would have the result. But how could we prove that $\alpha \ast (\beta \ast \delta)$ reparametrizes to $(\alpha \ast \beta) \ast \delta$?

Comment: It is entirely analogous to the operation on the path classes; the operations and proofs of associativity are literally the same. The fundamental group is just the maps from a point to itself in the path-class-groupoid

Comment: Just write down a suitable reparametrization. It has nothing to do with the paths themselves; consider a suitable piecewise-linear function $[0, 1] \to [0, 1]$. Think of $(\alpha * \beta) * \gamma$, for example, as spending $[0, \frac{1}{4}]$ running through $\alpha$, then $[\frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{2}]$ running through $\beta$; and then $[\frac{1}{2}, 1]$ running through $\gamma$; and adjust the points $\frac{1}{4}$ and $\frac{1}{2}$ accordingly as a function of the $t$ in $F_t$.

Comment: @anomaly The problem may be trying to write that path, I think it could be analogous to the homotopia class space, I don't see it at all clear sincerely

Comment: Associativity is addressed in https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4799502/42781, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/906647/42781, and https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1260737/42781.

Comment: @JohnPalmieri I see, it seems that the strategy they do in the links you showed me is based on defining an application that acts as the indicated homotopy. But how does this relate to this idea "$\alpha \ast (\beta \ast \delta)$ reparametrizes to $(\alpha \ast \beta) \ast \delta$", Is it the same idea?

Comment: Yes, it's the same idea, made precise.

Answer (score 0):

For the operation to be well defined suppose $\alpha\sim\alpha'$ and $\beta\sim\beta'$. We want to show $\alpha\ast\beta\sim\alpha'\ast\beta'$, i.e. there is an homotopy between $\alpha\ast\beta$ and $\alpha'\ast\beta'$.

Let $F$ be an homotopy between $\alpha$ and $\alpha'$ and $G$ be an homotopy between $\beta$ and $\beta'$.

Define $H\colon[0,1]\times I\to X$ by $H(s,t)=F(2s,t)$ for $0\leq s\leq \frac{1}{2}$ and by  $H(s,t)=G(2s-1,t)$ for $\frac{1}{2}\leq s \leq 1$.

It is straightforward to verify that $H$ is well defined and gives the homotopy you are looking for. Associativity works in a similar way.

Comment: had made a similar approach, but with $H(s, t)=F(s, 2t)$ for $0 \leq t \leq \frac{1}{2}$ and $H(s, t)=G(s, 2t-1)$ for $\frac{1}{2} \leq t \leq 1$ but I don't see it working, does your setting make it work?

Comment: The best thing is to draw the homotopy but it is hard on this website

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).